# Unable to use Autodispose in Android with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android, autodispose

I was trying to use AutoDispose https://github.com/uber/AutoDispose to dispose of my Rx streams in android.

But I am having an issue when I add it to my activity/fragment. I think it is a kotlin issue but I am not able to figure out what.

when I add `AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider.from(lifecycle)` I get an error on the from method in Android Studio and it won't compile.

This is the stack trace

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public final fun from(p0: (() -> Lifecycle)!): AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider! defined in com.uber.autodispose.android.lifecycle.AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider
public open fun from(p0: Lifecycle!): AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider! defined in com.uber.autodispose.android.lifecycle.AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider
public open fun from(p0: LifecycleOwner!): AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider! defined in com.uber.autodispose.android.lifecycle.AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider
```

The same code works with there sample app.

Comment: @zac-sweers when you get time can you check.

Comment: Can you confirm what's the class hierarchy of your `lifecycle` variable?

Comment: Can you paste a full reproducible sample snippet?

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have encounter same issue, it cause by compatibility of Lifecycle package Androidx support and previous v7 support, they are different in package artifact 
 naming.

[AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)
[Mirgration](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)
eg: artifact naming:

> com.android.support:appcompat-v7 ->   androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0

AppCompatActivity implemented LifecycleOwner that is the power under AutoDispose's work, but in latest version AutoDispose, they use AndroidX instead (see AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider.from(LifecycleOwner owner) 'LifecycleOwner' ), so owner can not be treat as right type if you use Non-Androidx with AutoDispose v1.1.0（AFAIK AutoDispose  v0.8.0 works well with com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0）

So, you can either use Migrate you app to AndroidX [Mirgration Guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) or use older version of AutoDispose. See [AutoDispose on mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.uber.autodispose).

About the change, see the changelog https://github.com/uber/AutoDispose/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-100 , v1.0.0 and later version depend on AndroidX, v1.0.0-RC3 should be our choice.

> Version 1.0.0
>   2018-10-10 Stable release! This is identical in functionality to 1.0.0-RC3 but completely migrated to the new AndroidX artifacts. From this point forward for Android projects, you must be on AndroidX artifacts. You can use 1.0.0-RC3 to ease migration if need be.

**Edit**: If you want RxKotlin like extension, go and copy: https://github.com/uber/AutoDispose/blob/master/sample/src/main/kotlin/com/uber/autodispose/recipes/subscriberproxies.kt